# Magento 2 - product details tab title as an clickable link url to another page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, xml, tabs

How to make the product details tab title is clickable link, and grab the SKU from the current product page to the link?

**For example**, I created a custom product tab called "**Download**", and when click on "**Download**" product detail tab, it will open a new tab for **www.abc.com/download/?keyword=SKU**

Comment: do you want to tab clickable Or inner title clickable ?

Comment: i want the tab to be clickable. Basically, no inner tab content. Is this something possible? Thanks.